# How to create fillable underscore text with small subtext under line

Tags: html

How can I create simple editable field without border for fillable line with underscore (like documents field for Name, Signature, etc) and with small text under this.

It's should look like

```
_______Den_Andreychuk________
         (name)
```

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is probably to create an adequately styled input field with a label underneath.

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
    <input name="name" style="background: transparent; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid black; text-align: center; line-height: 2; display: block; width: 100%;" value="Den Andreychuk" >
    <label for="name" style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; display: block;">(name)</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Small addition: you might want to change the `value` attribute to `placeholder` so that the user doesn't have to delete the sample name.